# Filter through custom taxonomy with an array of taxonomy IDs

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy

I'm currently storing a string of comma separated taxonomy IDs in a text field for each user. I have managed to retrieve the string from a user which I've saved in a variable called '$user_terms'. I can split this string into an array of IDs called '$user_terms_array. I'm stuck now though as I need to get the name of the IDs. I found this:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

but I'm not particularly sure how to use this/ if I can use this in my situation. I also found this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/

But again I can't quite figure out how to use this. I tried the following:

`$context['single_term'] = get_term( $user_terms_array[1], $taxonomy = 'terms' );`

Then in my twig template if I try to output the value of single_term I get the following output in the HTML:

'https://www.w3-edge.com/products/

Object Caching 4429/6070 objects using disk
Page Caching using disk: enhanced (User is logged in)
Database Caching using disk (Request-wide User is logged in)

Served from: dev.url @ 2017-08-22 10:28:00 by W3 Total Cache -->'

Not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

Edit:

I tried this:
`$context['single_term'] = get_term( $user_terms_array[1], $taxonomy = 'terms' )->name;`
and it get no output, it's just blank.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't enter such expression as second argument in `get_term()`. Enter directly the name of your taxonomy...
Are you dealing with simple post categories? If that's the case, your taxonomy name is `'category'`.

```
$context['single_term'] = get_term( $user_terms_array[1], 'category' );
```

Second, ensure that `$user_terms_array` contains term IDs as **integer**.

```
$user_terms_array = array_map( 'intval', explode( '-', $user_terms ) );
```

Then, you're on the good way. Using `WP_Term_Query` instead of `get_term()` wouldn't give you any pros if I refer to the supplied info. In this context, I'd stick with `get_term()`.